# Using gojs for UI automation

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, gojs

Is there any documentation on how to thoroughly use gojs for UI automation? I just want to drag and link controls that are on a pallet to a canvas to create a flow chart. Please help. I just need to be pointed to a tutorial or reference to get started.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you are asking for, but have you used the Robot class for simulating user inputs?
https://gojs.net/latest/extensions/Robot.html

```
// a shared Robot that can be used by all commands for this one Diagram
robot = new Robot(myDiagram);  // defined in Robot.js
```

Then one can do operations like:

```
function clickLambda() {
    var lambda = myDiagram.findNodeForKey("Lambda");
    if (lambda === null) return;
    var loc = lambda.location;

    // click on Lambda
    robot.mouseDown(loc.x + 10, loc.y + 10, 0, { });
    robot.mouseUp(loc.x + 10, loc.y + 10, 100, { });

    // Clicking is just a sequence of input events.
    // There is no command in CommandHandler for such a basic gesture.
}
```

or:

```
function dragFromPalette() {
    // simulate a drag-and-drop between Diagrams:
    var dragdrop = { sourceDiagram: myPalette, targetDiagram: myDiagram };
    robot.mouseDown(5, 5, 0, dragdrop); // this should be where the Alpha node is in the source myPalette
    robot.mouseMove(60, 60, 100, dragdrop);
    robot.mouseUp(100, 100, 200, dragdrop); // this is where the node will be dropped in the target myDiagram

    // If successful in dragging a node from the Palette into the Diagram,
    // the DraggingTool will perform a transaction.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the chrome browser and select the frame in which the GoJs is load.
Use the console and select the mainGoJs diagram name.

We use the following JavaScriptExecutor inside the Selenium Java file to automate a GoJs Organization Chart.

```java
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(""
        + "for(let i = 0; i <"+count+"; i++)"
        + "{"
        + "var key= dgmOrganizationUnit.model.nodeDataArray[i].key;"
        + "var node = dgmOrganizationUnit.findNodeForKey(key);"
        + "var ntxt= node.text; "
        + "if (ntxt==='"+ parentname+"')"
        + "{"
        + "dgmOrganizationUnit.centerRect(node.actualBounds);"
        + "dgmOrganizationUnit.select(node);"
        + "}"
        + "}"
        );
```

*dgmOrganizationUnit* is the main GoJs ORG Unit Frame Containter. Enter a similar name available in your application on the chrome DevTools "console" and you would see all the parameters popping up.